# How do I fix CS0433 errors in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

The line of code that causes it any place referencing type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` whether as a variable type, or in a Using Declaration.

This Using declaration worked fine and made my classes less disgusting than having to write  `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>` in 100 places in my class.  Taking the Using declarations out does not solve my problem, it just moves it to the places where the dictionary type is used in my method parameters.

Full error text:

```
CS0433  The type 'Dictionary<TKey, TValue>' exists in both
'System.Collections, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' 
 and 
'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'   ProjectName.DNX
```

This error occurs in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 template based projects using DNX 1.0.0-beta7, having some Model and Controller classes that reference generic collection types.  The project.json is set thus:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
```

The sample problem occurs if you just have it say:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
```

- The line of code that causes it is a Using declaration, a type alias of sorts, that worked fine until I try to convert a beta6 project to beta7.
- Conversion proceeds until I try to add these using JsonDictionary aliases, then compilation breaks.

I have searched this error code and it has a long and Inglorious history in ASP.NET.

What causes this problem? And how can I fix it, since I can't remove mscorlib from my project, nor can I remove System.Collections?

Comment: Why can't you remove the reference to `System.Collections.dll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In beta6 when you created a class library project it would setup the frameworks section the way you posted with "dotnet"
but if you create a new class library project in beta7 it will set it up like this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23225",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23225",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23225",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23225",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23225"
      }
    }
  }
```

I believe that if you update your project json accordingly it will solve the problem.

Comment: My main asp.net project plus a Class Library that it depended on were configured inconsistently, and fixing both their project.jsons was necessary. What was a surprise was that incorrect values in a Dependant sub-assembly broke compilation of the main assembly.  I would have expected that bad valuesin the Dependant assembly would break ITS compilation. But nope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify it as a framework dependency.

```
"frameworks": {
     "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
         "System.Collections":  ""
       }
     }
}
```