# vNext: <Type> exists in both <SomeNamespace> and <SomeOtherNamespace>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, coreclr

I just upgraded to the beta 7 of ASP.NET 5 vNext and some of my code now has some errors because of conflicting namespaces. I'm using DNX 4.5.1 (but wouldn't mind moving everything to DNX Core, now that CoreCLR is complete).

One example is WebUtiliy. For instance, this code:

```
string soandso = WebUtility.UrlEncode(someString)
```

This returns the error below:

> The type 'WebUtility' exists in both 'System.Runtime.Extensions,
>   Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   and 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I'm not explicitly using System.Runtime.Extensions (in either the "using" statements at the beginning of the file, nor in the project.json dependencies). I have other areas of the code where a similar issue happen.

My question is: how do I get rid of this 'properly? How do I figure out where the collisions come from? Would moving to DNX Core solve this (or make it easier to troubleshoot)?

Comment: if you update your question with the contents of the project.json file[s] in your projects then I think I can help you. possibly similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485198/how-do-i-fix-cs0433-errors-in-asp-net-5/32488337#32488337

Comment: You need to show your project.json file. Most likely some packages/runtime packages haven't been updated to beta7

Comment: Can you please share the `project.json` file?

Comment: Unfortunately I've played around a lot with the project.json so it's not entirely matching the issue now. I found the root cause though I think. This is caused when you try to have both a DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core project. It can happen that a shared dependencies is redundant with one specific to DNX Core, hence the issue. The solution is to move the shared dependency to DNX 4.5.1 "frameworkAssemblies" to separate them clearly. Unfortunately VS Studio doesn't make it very clear which ones are causing the issue so it's a lot of trial and error :(